# how to clone and re draw google chart in another div?

Tags: google-visualization, pivottable.js

I am having a hard time to figure out how to do this, since i am not that familiar with google chart.

I am using pivotTable.js and everything is working okay, but i want to "save" or have a button where the current created chart will be cloned to another div.

I made a global variable

```
var wrapper;
```

this to save the chart

```
 wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      dataTable: dataTable,
      chartType: chartType,
      options: options
    });
    wrapper.draw(result[0]);
```

After this, when the button is clicked the wrapper chart, should be redrawn in another div.

```
<div id="trial" style="margin: 30px;"></div>
```

I tried to do this but i am stock with how will i put the chart into the trial div.

```
  // Never called.
      google.visualization.events.addListener(wrapper, 'onmouseover', uselessHandler);


      google.visualization.events.addListener(wrapper, 'ready', onReady);


      // Never called
      function uselessHandler() {
        alert("I am never called!");
      }

      function onReady() {
        google.visualization.events.addListener(wrapper.getChart(), 'click', usefulHandler);
      }

      // Called
      function usefulHandler() {
        alert(wrapper.getChart());
      }
```

SOLVED:

```
   function getChart() {
  google.visualization.events.addListener(wrapper, 'ready', onReady);
      function onReady() {
        google.visualization.events.addListener(wrapper.getChart(), 'click', usefulHandler);
      }
    var trialChart = wrapper.clone();
    trialChart.setContainerId('trial');
    trialChart.draw();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after `clone()` -- just need to set the new `containerId`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', '2015');
    data.addColumn('number', '2016');
    data.addRows([
       [new Date('01/01/2016'), 200, 210],
       [new Date('01/02/2016'), 190, 220],
       [new Date('01/03/2016'), 205, 200],
       [new Date('01/04/2016'), 220, 230],
       [new Date('01/05/2016'), 212, 210],
       [new Date('01/06/2016'), 185, 193],
       [new Date('01/07/2016'), 196, 207]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'LineChart',
      containerId: 'chart_orig',
      dataTable: data,
      options: {
        height: 400
      }
    });

    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      document.getElementById('cloneBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var trialChart = chart.clone();
        trialChart.setContainerId('chart_trial');
        trialChart.draw();
      }, false);
    });

    chart.draw();
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="cloneBtn" value="Clone" />
<div>Original Chart</div>
<div id="chart_orig"></div>
<div>Trial Chart</div>
<div id="chart_trial"></div>
```

Comment: thank you, but instead of clicking the chart.. the user will click a button? i am not really familiar with google.. sorry

Comment: oh btw, is there a way to append the charts into the div?

Comment: not sure I follow, each chart needs a separate div -- but you can have multiple divs in some "parent" div...?

Comment: That little nugget of `clone()` and `setContainerId` helped big time to solve the problem of creating a larger yet fully interactive version of original chart in a new container...