# Change Google Chart container to another during runtime

Tags: javascript, dom, charts, google-visualization

Like in this answer:

[how to clone and re draw google chart in another div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38532646/how-to-clone-and-re-draw-google-chart-in-another-div)

However, I don't want to clone the chart itself, but move him to another div in runtime.

Comment: Why downvote my question? I think that's pretty clear. I don't found any explanation on whole internet about change the div of an google chart to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are some options...

1) if using the `ChartWrapper` class,
simply use `setContainerId` to change the div id
then redraw the chart

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');
  data.addRows([
    [0, 0],
    [3, 3],
    [6, 6]
  ]);

  var chartWrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    containerId: 'chart-left',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      theme: 'maximized'
    }
  });
  chartWrapper.draw();

  document.getElementById('switch').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var containerId = (chartWrapper.getContainerId() === 'chart-left') ? 'chart-right' : 'chart-left';
    chartWrapper.setContainerId(containerId);
    chartWrapper.draw();
  }, false);
}
```

```css
.chart {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.chart:first-child {
  background: cyan;
}

.chart:last-child {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="switch" type="button" value="Switch"/>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="chart" id="chart-left"></div>
  <div class="chart" id="chart-right"></div>
</div>
```

---

2) if using a standard chart class, such as `LineChart`,
you will need to re-create the chart using the new container,
then draw

you will have to clear the previous chart
you can use chart method --> `clearChart`
or simply clear the div --> `div.innerHTML = ''`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');
  data.addRows([
    [0, 0],
    [3, 3],
    [6, 6]
  ]);

  var container = '';
  document.getElementById('switch').addEventListener('click', drawChart, false);
  drawChart();

  function drawChart() {
    if (container !== '') {
      document.getElementById(container).innerHTML = '';
    }
    container = (container === 'chart-left') ? 'chart-right' : 'chart-left';
    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(
      document.getElementById(container)
    );
    chart.draw(data, {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      theme: 'maximized'
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.chart {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.chart:first-child {
  background: cyan;
}

.chart:last-child {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="switch" type="button" value="Switch"/>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="chart" id="chart-left"></div>
  <div class="chart" id="chart-right"></div>
</div>
```

---

3) you could also use static method --> `google.visualization.drawChart`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');
  data.addRows([
    [0, 0],
    [3, 3],
    [6, 6]
  ]);

  var container = '';
  document.getElementById('switch').addEventListener('click', drawChart, false);
  drawChart();

  function drawChart() {
    if (container !== '') {
      document.getElementById(container).innerHTML = '';
    }
    container = (container === 'chart-left') ? 'chart-right' : 'chart-left';
    google.visualization.drawChart({
      containerId: container,
      dataTable: data,
      chartType: 'LineChart',
      options: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        theme: 'maximized'
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.chart {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.chart:first-child {
  background: cyan;
}

.chart:last-child {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="switch" type="button" value="Switch"/>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="chart" id="chart-left"></div>
  <div class="chart" id="chart-right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!
I didn't know the chart wrapper. In fact, i run some tests on methods 1 and 3.

The method 1 runs perfectly, it's the solution of my problem. 

The method 3 has memory leak on execution. Each time you switch the charts, a new chart is created and the memory increase, this make me think that the chart is not moving, but recreated on each execution.

Comment: cheers! didn't think about memory impact, option 1) is definitely way to go, thanks...